# Equation number is too far from the equation

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to number some equations in a document that I'm writing, but the numbers are to the extreme right of page and I want it to be next to the equation.

Right now, for example, it looks like:

[code screenshot 1 http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_34cc3ed13650d4d641be7fde24578fe2_l3.png](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_34cc3ed13650d4d641be7fde24578fe2_l3.png)

While I want it to be:

[code screenshot 2 http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_3715e9b1fb12ce571313313b95b41716_l3.png](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_3715e9b1fb12ce571313313b95b41716_l3.png)

Is there any command that I can write in preamble to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, LaTeX puts equation numbers flush with the margin (for flush left use `\documentclass[leqno]{...}`). The reason for this, I suspect, is that this makes it much easier for the reader to find the equation numbers by scanning down the left or right margin.

If you really want to change the default behaviour, and ignore best practice and all the thought that has gone into the design of (La)TeX, I suggest using something like the following:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\newcommand\Label[1]{\qquad\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \[
     a^2+b^2=c^2\Label{E:Pythagoras}
  \]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

What this does is define a new command `\Label` that inserts an equation number after a `\qquad` skip to the right of the equation and gives it the corresponding `\label`. I strongly believe that you should not give an equation a number if you are not going to refer to it later, so using `\Label` to insert the equation number should not be costing you any "extra" typing.

[There may be a standard package for doing something like this but I don't know of one.]

Comment: Doesn't work if you're trying to label each equation in an align environment.

Comment: @StatsSorceress I agree, this won't work inside an `align` environment because `align` plays with the alignment of the equation quite a lot and, more importantly, it places it's own equation number. If you want this feature with alignment then you should use an `align*`-environment so as to disable the environments automatic labeling of equations. Doing this with the code above produces reasonable results. If this is not quite what you want then  I suggest asking a new question in which you say exactly what your requirements are.